# SQL Server Exception: "The column name xxx is not valid" when using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm getting a strange error from the SQL Server JDBC driver. It is telling me that a column name is invalid even though the column is present, correctly named and the same query works fine when executed in SqlServer Management Studio.

The error is:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name MarginCall is not valid.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:626)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getBigDecimal(SQLServerResultSet.java:2570)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBigDecimal(DelegatingResultSet.java:305)
...
```

Comment: Can you include the offending code? Does the name match the values you get in ResultSet.getColumnNames?

Comment: This has happen to me when I was excluding the existing column from the table.
To resolve this problem you can select '*' first i.e all the records and then try to included columns one by one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a simple mistake by me.

My query was using an 'AS' clause in the select statement. I was trying to retrieve the column value from the ResultSet using the actual column name, instead of the column alias defined in the AS clause.

Schoolboy error. Apologies for the time wasting.

Many thanks to Steve B. for his suggestion to use ResultSet.getColumnNames(). Although the actual method call I used was ResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(columnIndex);

Answer (score 1):

Check the case of your table name. if collation is set to case sensitive on ms sql server the table names are affected too.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue can be thrown, if the `Entity` *properties* & `SELECT` statement *column* values are mismatching.

Check the following example:

**Entity**

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;

    private String code;
}
```

**Repository**

```java
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT id, name FROM country WHERE isActive = 'true' ORDER BY name")
    List<Country> findIdAndNameAndCodeByIsActiveTrue();
}
```

In this case it will throw an Exception

```java
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name code is not valid.
```

So, if you do not need all the columns as response, then use [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html) as return type or mention all the columns which are available as part of `entity` in the `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the column name inside square brackets: [MarginCall]
Just a guess.

Comment: I'm afraid that wasn't the problem but thanks very much for the suggestion.